# SQL - read CSV file with unexpected EOF error

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I need to read data from .csv file which contains many records, but in last row
there is string "the_end" and after that there is no LF sign.

Here is my csv file:

```
1,James,Smith,19750101
2,Meggie,Smith,19790122
3,Robert,Smith,20071101
4,Alex,Smith,20040202
the_end
```

Below my sql script which reads data into temporary table:

```
create table #Data 
(
id int,
first_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50),
birthdate smalldatetime
)


bulk insert #Data
from 'C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\csvtest.csv'
with
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)


select * from #Data

drop table #Data
```

Error is:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>   Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I want to read all data into my table without this last line label "the_end", that's obvious. How can i manage that? I cannot modify this file, because it's given from outside and I cannot do that.

Comment: Copy it and modify it?

Comment: what do you mean? copy data to table and what?

Comment: "*I cannot modify this file, because it's given from outside and I cannot do that.*" Copy the file. Remove the offending line. Import the copy.

Comment: how can I do that from sql script

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SQL script. Modify the file either by hand (if it only has to be done once) or with a program, then feed the modified file to the script.

Comment: I don't think that's optimal solution, I have more than 20 files and with more than 10 000 lines in each of them at server

Comment: It's not optimal, but it will do the job. 10,000 lines is pretty small, and 20 files aren't much. You could do it by hand in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**`lastrow`** option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)

```
bulk insert #Data
from 'C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\csvtest.csv'
with
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
, lastrow = 4
)
```

dynamic sql example using a variable for lastline:

```
create table #Data (
    id int
  , first_name varchar(50)
  , last_name varchar(50)
  , birthdate smalldatetime
);

declare @lastline int = 4;

declare @sql nvarchar(max)= '
bulk insert #Data
from ''C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\csvtest.csv''
with (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
  , ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
  , lastrow = '+convert(nvarchar(11),@lastline)+'
);';
exec sp_executesql @sql;

select * from #Data

drop table #Data
```

Comment: did you read exaclty my post? I have different files and in each of them in another line there is end of file.. 4 or 3333 or 34 or 22332 ...

Comment: @mike_pl I did read your post. Your post didn't mention multiple files or that you had no idea which row should be the last row.

Comment: So now you know thath :)

Comment: @mike_pl if you want to know how many lines are in a file, you can use `find /v /c "" C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\csvtest.csv` from a windows command prompt and it will tell you.

Comment: It won't help me ! I wrote about that, because, i cannot assign variable to LASTROW .. :/ it's foribbden

Comment: ... you could execute the bulk insert with dynamic sql and use a variable that way... unless you mean forbidden as in religious reasons...

Comment: what do you mean? when I have variable like @linesCount and assign that to lastrow it's not working

Comment: Could not find stored procedure '
bulk insert #Data
from 'C:\Users\Michał\Desktop\csvtest.csv'
with (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
  , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
  , LASTROW = 0
);'.

Comment: try `exec(@sql)` or `exec sp_executesql @sql`

Comment: works, but I have another problem , I have variable lastline and I have to pass value which equals lastline -1 , (without last line), i cannot do that:
declare count int
set count = lastline - 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Answer (score 0):

If the lastrow option doesn't work for you, manually delete the last row and try to re-run your BulkLoad process.  If everything works fine, crate a VB.NET executable to open the file, strip out the last row, and re-save the file.   can schedule the delete-last-row process and the BulkLoad process using the Windows Task Scheduler.

https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html